# How do I say that something is "negative"?

Tags: vocabulary, usage

I'm trying to explain to a Chinese penpal that certain word and phrases in English carry a negative connotation and so shouldn't be used in specific situations.

I want to say "that phrase is very negative" (as in lacking in optimism or positivity). Google translate gives the word `negative` as `消极`, but looking 消极 up in a Chinese to English dictionary tells me it means "passive", which isn't at all what I'm going for.

What's the right word to use?

Comment: has user looked up iciba? at entry for "negative" users can find sample sentences with the required meaning

Comment: @S.Rhee Nope, I hadn't heard of that site until you just mentioned it. Looks like a great resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to [iCIBA](http://www.iciba.com/negative):

If someone is a negative person, or has a negative attitude, then they are `消极 (xiāo jí)`, or  `悲观 (bēi guān)`.

To say that a word has a negative connotation, you use `负面含义 (fùmiàn hányì)`, literally, "downside meaning".

Thanks to S.Rhee for pointing me to iCIBA, where I was able to find the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 3):

Consider: **贬义词**:

> derogatory term; pejorative -(ABC)

> derogatory term; expression of censure -(A Chinese English Dictionaty)

两岸 lists a defintion with some examples of these 贬义词:

> 帶有否定、厭惡等感情色彩的詞（與「褒義詞」相對）。如「昏庸」、「卑鄙」、「討厭」等。也作「貶詞」。

and an example of usage:

> ‘爱情’二字在他的特别词典里是个贬义词, 跟‘贪污’、‘盗窃’、‘资本主义’等词语一样的难听。 -(周克芹 《许茂和他的女儿们》第四章)